# relating quartic form and trilinear forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a non-singular quartic homogeneous polynomial. Assume that $$
f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i, j, k, \ell=1}^{n} f_{i j k \ell} x_{i} x_{j} x_{k} x_{\ell}
$$
for $f_{i j k \ell} \in \mathbb{Z}$ that are symmetric in the indices. We may then define the trilinear forms
$$
L_{i}(\mathbf{w} ; \mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{y}):=4 ! \sum_{j, k, \ell=1}^{n} f_{i j k \ell} w_{j} x_{k} z_{\ell}
$$
for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$.

I think I understand how the author got to this definition:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
f(\mathbf{w,x,y;z}):=f(\mathbf{w+x+y+z})-f(\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{y+z})-f(\mathbf{x+y+z})+f(\mathbf{y+z}) \\ -f(\mathbf{w+x+z})+f(\mathbf{w+z})+f(\mathbf{x+z})-f(\mathbf{z})
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$

With the definition of trilinear forms $L_{i}(\mathbf{w} ; \mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{y})$ for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$ we see that:

$$
f(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} ; \mathbf{z})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i} L_{i}(\mathbf{w} ; \mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{y})+g(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})
$$

where $g(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ is independent of $\mathbf{z}$.

Sadly I don't see why or how $f(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} ; \mathbf{z})$ can be related to the trilinear form. Why are those things the same?
Any hint or help to understand the trilinear form would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a mistake in the definition of the trilinear form and that it should be $y_l$ instead of $z_l$?

Comment: yes it should be $y_l$ instead of $z_l$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $F(z,w,x,y) = \sum_{i,j,z,l} f_{ijzl} z_i w_j x_k y_l$. Then

- $f(x) = f(x, x, x, x)$
- $F(z, w, x, y) = F(\text{any permutation of x,y,z,w}) = \frac{1}{24} \sum_i z_i L_i(w, x, y)$, just by pulling out the $z$ coefficient in each multinomial.

Note that $F$ is multi-linear. So we can evaluate
$$
\begin{align*}
f(w, x, y;z) &= f(w+x+y+z) - \cdots \\ 
&= F(w + x + y + z, w + x + y + z, w + x + y + z, w + x + y + z) - \cdots
\end{align*}
$$
by expanding multi-linearly. For example, the first term would expand into $4^4$ terms.

We can then see what kind of $F(a,b,c,d)$ would remain after the whole expansion. As two examples,

- Consider $F(x,y,z,w)$, i.e. all four variables show up

  - This term shows up in $f(x+y+z+w)$.
  - But this term doesn't show up in $f(w+y+z)$, since the expansion of $f(w+y+z)$ can only involve $w,y,z$, while the term we are considering ($F(x,y,z,w)$) involves $x$.
  - Similarly, this term won't show up in any remaining part of $f(w,x,y;z)$.
  - So $F(x,y,z,w)$ will show up exactly once in $f(w,x,y;z)$.
- Consider $F(w,y,z,w)$.

  - This term shows up in $f(x+y+z+w)$, with coefficient +1.
  - This term also shows up in $f(w+y+z)$, with coefficient -1.
  - This term doesn't show up anywhere else.
  - So $F(w,y,z,w)$ will not show up in the final expression in $f(w,x,y;z)$, since 1 - 1 = 0.

Overall, since $w,x,y$ plays a symmetric role here, you basically need to consider these seven cases of $F(a,b,c,d)$ where the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ equals

- $\{w, x, y, z\}$
- $\{w, x, z\}$
- $\{w, z\}$
- $\{z\}$
- $\{w, x, y\}$
- $\{w, x\}$
- $\{w\}$

You can check that only $\{w, x, y, z\}$ and $\{w, x, y\}$ would contribute to $f(w, x, y; z)$. So
$$f(w, x, y, z) = \sum_{\{a,b,c,d\} = \{w, x, y, z\}} F(a,b,c,d) + \sum_{\{a, b, c, d\} = \{w, x, y\}} F(a,b,c,d)$$

There are $4! = 24$ terms in the first sum and they are all equal to $F(z,w,x,y)$; the first sum is thus $\sum_i z_i L_i(w, x, y)$. The second sum is the $g(w,x,y)$ expression you have there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. I think I understand it better now. Just to make sure tho: $$f(w+z)=F(w+z,w+z,w+z,w+z)=F(w,w,w,w)+4(w,w,w,z)+6F(w,w,z,z)+4F(w,z,z,z)+F(z,z,z,z)$$
Would this expansion be right?

Comment: No, because the order matters, e.g. $F(w,w,w,z)$ may not equal $F(w,w,z,w)$, unless there's known symmetry in the coefficient $f_{ijzl}$. So you have to write out the $2^4$ terms unfortunately.

Comment: Oh actually, now that I reread your question - you did say that $f_{ijzl}$ is symmetric in indices. If that's the case, then your expression is correct. (I believe my answer doesn't depend on that though)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer again!  :)